# How to animate between paths in SVG file with D3?

Tags: d3.js, svg-animate

I have a SVG file with 5 paths, each one has a different id assigned. The paths are exported from Illustrator.

```
<svg ...>
  <path id="state1" fill="#DDD" d="M274.727,341.564c-45.393,11.342-52....." />
  <path id="state2" fill="#DDD" d="....." />
```

How do I animate between the 5 id states in D3? In [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) this can be easily done with

`stage1.animate({"path" : (stage2.attr("path"))}, 1000);`

Thanks!

Comment: Get the `d` attributes for each, then assign to the path you want to modify in turn with `.transition()` in between.

Comment: It's actually that simple, thanks! I had problems with my path exported from Illustrator, that's why it wasn't working at first. When I deleted the newline characters (put the whole "d" string in one line), it worked.